# How to upload an audio file with ID3 tags into an application using C# and visual studio

Tags: c#, uwp, id3

I am currently working on code to pull an mp3 file from a user's computer and upload it into a music library application that I am creating in visual studio UWP using C#. It needs to be able to pull the ID3 tags for artist, title, and album, as these will all have to be referenced on the actual library page, where the music will be sorted accordingly.

The following code is what I have so far, and I am currently stuck on what else to write just to upload the file into the music library portion of my app with the ID3 tags:

```
 //Uploading Music File Button
    private async void UploadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Opening User's personal Music Library to select files
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
        {
            ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation =
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary
        };
        //Accepted file type = mp3 (only mp3 files display for user selection)
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file 
            //Storing File for future use
Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);

            // Open a stream for the selected file. 
            // The 'using' block ensures the stream is disposed 
            // after the music is loaded. 
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
            await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        }
}
```

I am very new to all this, so I may be missing some very obvious things in this code. I have checked into various tutorials and examples, but none of them provide the exact fit I'm looking for or are half done. Thank you for taking the time to read my code and offer any advice/suggestions.

Comment: ID3 is a metadata container most often used in conjunction with the MP3 audio file format. So your question is uploading file or edit ID3 tag?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Sorry about the confusion...I need both. I'm wanting to move the mp3 file to a folder and also be able to access the ID3 tags to use them on another page for sorting purposes.

Comment: For accessing audio metadata, you could use [`MusicProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties)class, and upload the audio you could use [`BackgroundTransfer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer) api. this is code upload file [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer).

Answer (score 1):

> How to upload an audio file with ID3 tags into an application using C# and visual studio

For accessing audio metadata, you could use [`GetMusicPropertiesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getmusicpropertiesasync) method to get audio file's album artist title `MusicProperties` property.

```
try
{
    StorageFile file = rootPage.sampleFile;
    if (file != null)
    {
        StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();

        // Get music properties
        MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
        outputText.AppendLine("Album: " + musicProperties.Album);
        outputText.AppendLine("Rating: " + musicProperties.Rating);
    }
}
// Handle errors with catch blocks
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
 // For example, handle a file not found error
}
```

For uploading the audio file to server, you could use [`BackgroundTransfer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer) api. and this is [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer) you could refer to. And you could also you [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) API to post your file stream.