# i can't read info from ID3 tags in uwp App

Tags: c#, uwp, id3v2

I have a c# UWP app. For an add break i need to read ID3 tags for DAI.

I am registering for timeMetadataTracksChanged event and then registering for CueEntered event. These are both firing correctly and i can read the id3 tag header but not the rest of the data. How do i do this?

```
    private void metadata_ID3CueEntered(TimedMetadataTrack timedMetadataTrack, MediaCueEventArgs args)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("metadata_ID3CueEntered");
                Debug.WriteLine("id: "+args.Cue.Id.ToString());
                var dataCue = args.Cue as DataCue;
                Debug.WriteLine("dispatch type: " + timedMetadataTrack.DispatchType);
                Debug.WriteLine("trackLabel: " + timedMetadataTrack.Label.ToString());
                    if (dataCue != null && dataCue.Data != null)
                {
                    // The payload is the raw ID3 bytes found in a TS stream
                    // Ref: http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure
                    var dr = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(dataCue.Data);
                var header_version_major = dr.ReadByte();
                var header_version_minor = dr.ReadByte();
                var header_flags = dr.ReadByte();
                var header_tagSize = dr.ReadUInt32();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"ID3 tag data: major {header_version_major}, minor: {header_version_minor}");
                }
            }
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269810/7254781) may help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was very easy in the end although did take me a day to figure it out.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(dataCue.Data.ToArray())
```